# How big is Cooper Station?

Tags: interstellar

The scene in which kids were playing baseball shows the curvature of the station and it seemed very small to host a colony. But later, it looked very big to host several buildings and agriculture land.

How big is Cooper Station exactly?

Comment: There is nothing I could find, in final scripts, original scripts or interviews that seems to clearly define a size, but it’s big, I guess

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's nothing in the [script](http://www.raindance.org/wp-content/uploads/FLFinalSPv1.pdf) or the [novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21488063-interstellar) other than that it's vast and huge.

> ...[**VAST** CYLINDRICAL STATION]

and

> ...*the **huge** cylinder spun on its axis*

---

That being said, we can 'eyeball' the size based on what we see in the film:

- These are hay bales

  [image]
- Since hay bales are typically around 4-5 feet, we can use them to estimate the size of the circumference. A few frames later we see both sides of the station.

  [image]

  Which works out to 1700 bales of hay wide or almost exactly **1 mile diameter** (3.14 miles circumference).
- In the next shot we that Cooper is sitting looking down toward the northern pole. His house appears to be at the precise halfway point with ten (equally spaced?) sections between him and the light. In the next shot we see him looking at the southern pole which appears to be equally distant from him. Using the same measure, we can see that each section is approx 750ft in width. This gives us an (rough approximate) of **2.75 miles in length.**

  [image]

Comment: And yes, this makes an absolute nonsense of the baseball scene but let's pretend that the poles taper to the point that you can hit something that far.

Comment: Can you please convert that to metric units? I have no idea how big it is from the description.

Comment: @Fabian - Sure. It's 1609344 mm x 4425696 mm

Comment: In furlongs, please!

Comment: @OrganicMarble - It's 0.000000000000170108 light-years wide and 0.000000000000467796 light-years long.

Comment:  Perfect. Real unit purists use only light years for distances.